# How to do pop before smtp with Zend Mail?

Tags: zend-framework, smtp, pop3

I just started to use Zend Mail Compoment and i need pop before smtp, but in the zend mail doc no mention about that.

Can anyone advise on that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POP before SMTP is not part of the SMTP standard, it's just a hack used to check that the client connecting to the SMTP server has valid credentials, without using SMTP's own authentication mechanisms.

Just use the Zend framework to [open the POP mailbox yourself](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html#zend.mail.read-example), and then send the mail via SMTP.